# Android + база данных

Tags: база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

Предположим есть готовая база, пусть на SQLite.
Может у кого есть готовые примеры для работы?
Хочется посмотреть, как правильно отобразить данные в табличном виде на экране.

Как добавлять, редактировать и удалять записи.
Разработка формы редактирования, особенно если полей разнотипных довольно много.

Как работать со справочниками? Например на форме редактирования как сделать выбор данных из справочника?
Хочется именно в Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос у вас большой. Его нужно разделить на два пункта.

1. Чтение базы данных
2. Вывод информации

Вопрос первый рассмотрим.
Есть база данных Fuelbase. Она объявлена в классе (сокращённо):

```
public class Fuelbase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fuel_XR";
   public static final String TABLE_FUEL = "fuel";
   public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
   public static final String FUEL_DATE = "fuel_date"; // дата записи
   public static final String FUEL_TIME = "fuel_time"; // время записи
   public static final String FUEL_TYPE = "fuel_type"; // тип топлива
}
```

В нашем сервисе объявляем переменные

```
SQLiteDatabase database;
Fuelbase dbFuelbase;
Cursor cursor;
```

Далее в теле функций

```
dbFuelbase = new Fuelbase(getApplicationContext());
database = dbFuelbase.getWritableDatabase();
```

Выборка данных  по полям

```
selection = "(fuel_type = '" + selection_type_search + "') AND (fuel_date between " + data_start_search_form + " AND " + data_end_search_form + ")";
```

Запрос в базу данных

```
cursor = database.query(Fuelbase.TABLE_FUEL, null, selection, null, null, null, null);
```

Обработка ответа на запрос

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        int IDIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Fuelbase.KEY_ID);
        String f_date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Fuelbase.FUEL_DATE));
        String f_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Fuelbase.FUEL_TIME));
        String f_type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Fuelbase.FUEL_TYPE));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
} else {
// результатов нет
}
cursor.close();
dbFuelbase.close();
database.close();
```

Для внесения новой записи:

```
dbFuelbase = new Fuelbase(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase database2 = dbFuelbase.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();
contentValues2.put(Fuelbase.FUEL_DATE, editprobeg.getText().toString());
contentValues2.put(Fuelbase.FUEL_TIME, getMilliFromDate(data_rec_fuel.getText().toString()));
contentValues2.put(Fuelbase.FUEL_TYPE, type_fuel);
database2.insert(Fuelbase.TABLE_FUEL, null, contentValues2);
dbFuelbase.close();
database2.close();
```

Для редактирования записи получаете номер строки. У меня вывод реализован через RecyclerView

```
FuelForm.Fuel movie = fuels.get(position);
String Id_rec = movie.getId_list();
```

Далее запрос

```
database = dbFuelbase.getWritableDatabase();
cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + Fuelbase.TABLE_FUEL
                        + " where " + Fuelbase.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{Id_rec});
if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     String f_date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Fuelbase.FUEL_DATE));
     String f_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Fuelbase.FUEL_TIME));
     String f_type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Fuelbase.FUEL_TYPE));
}
```

и сохраняем

```
dbFuelbase = new Fuelbase(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase database2 = dbFuelbase.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();
contentValues2.put(Fuelbase.FUEL_DATE, editprobeg.getText().toString());
contentValues2.put(Fuelbase.FUEL_TIME, getMilliFromDate(data_rec_fuel.getText().toString()));
contentValues2.put(Fuelbase.FUEL_TYPE, type_fuel);
database2.update(Fuelbase.TABLE_FUEL, contentValues2, Fuelbase.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[]{Id_rec});
dbFuelbase.close();
database2.close();
```